# python firestore issue with authentication

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using python with firestore, and trying to create a client in the backend. I am following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) tutorial

with the following code

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
cred = credentials.Certificate("cred_file.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.Client()
ref = db.collections(u'table')
```

and getting the following error

> google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not
>   automatically determine credentials. Please set
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and
>   re-run the application. For more information

I guess that is something wrong with the default credentials, what I don't get is, if I am initializing the credentials in my code, why does the app keep throwing an error for the default credentials? I am giving it the proper cred file explicitly.

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to download a service account key (a JSON file) then set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to that file on your device.

```
credential_path = "D:\****.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path
```

Don't forget to import the library os by `import os`

See https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers for more details.

Comment: I got the key, but the question is, why do i need to set the env variable if i am setting the authentication file explicitly in code?

Comment: see this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart under Initialize on your own server - what is the difference? I followed this

Comment: @thebeancounter It is a preferred method since it does not require code change if you i.e. need to deploy the same code to multiple environments or if your keys get compromised and you need to create new ones.