# Run Firestore emulator with Python in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, github-actions

I have a python package which is using `Firestore`. I'm trying to write GitHub actions before this I was using **Travis** now I want to shift on GitHub Actions. Everything is working fine on **Travis** but on GitHub Actions I'm getting error.

**Error:** (This error is not issue emulator should have to work without auth becuase it is working in some other repos but not on this)

> E:   google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

**Workflow (not working):** [Repo FireO Python](https://github.com/octabytes/FireO)

```
name: Python package

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install pytest
          python -m pip install -e .

      - name: Setup NodeJS
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"
      - name: Start Firestore emulator
        run: |
          npm i -g firebase firebase-tools
          firebase setup:emulators:firestore
          firebase emulators:start --only firestore &

      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest
        env:
          FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: localhost:8080
```

I don't know why the firestore emulator is not working. I have another repo where it is working fine.

**Working in another Repo WorkFlow** [Repo FireO NodeJs](https://github.com/octabytes/fireo-nodejs)

```
    name: Node.js CI

    on:
    push:
        branches: [main]
    pull_request:

    jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        strategy:
        matrix:
            node-version: [12.x, 14.x, 15.x]
            # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
            uses: actions/setup-node@v1
            with:
            node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

        - name: Install Firestore CLI and start emulators
            run: |
                npm i -g firebase firebase-tools
                firebase setup:emulators:firestore
                firebase emulators:start --only firestore &
        - name: Test Fireo Package
            run: |
                npm ci
                npm test
            env:
                FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: localhost:8080
```

Can you please point out what I'm missing what is wrong when I try to test it with python?

To run emulators you don't have to authenticate anything Here in this [Repo](https://github.com/octabytes/fireo-nodejs) where it is working without auth but on this [Repo](https://github.com/octabytes/FireO) where I have python it is not working. I wonder why it is working in some place and not in other

**UPDATE**

I try to set project id via env `GCLOUD_PROJECT="your-project-id"` and via command flag `--project` and it still not working. Because issue is not related to `id` I think some how python `pytest` is not able to detect that firestore emulator is running. I don't know why this is happening maybe due to language difference firestore is running on `npm` and test are running in `python` Maybe GitHub set both things in different places. Because everything is working on **NodeJS Repo** because firestore and tests are both running on `nodeJS` I think somehow we have to sync both of them in one place so they can detect each other.

Comment: 1. To set up the emulator on a local environment, try following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore).
2. This github [thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/issues/207) explains about the same error which you are facing. Try out the link mentioned in this thread, it might help you solve this error.

Comment: There is nothing which is explaining my issue

Comment: Isnt this the same issue? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947486/python-firestore-issue-with-authentication.
How are you authenticating to Gcloud?

Comment: @AlbinPaul To run emulators you don't have to authenticate anything I mention another repo where it is working without auth but on this repo where I have python it is not working. I wonder why it is working in some place and not in other

Answer (score 7):

I think you just need to set a project ID, as described in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore).

When connecting to the Cloud Firestore emulator from any other environment, you will need to specify a project ID. You can pass a project ID to initializeApp directly or set the GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable. Note that you do not need to use your real Firebase project ID; the Cloud Firestore emulator will accept any project ID, as long as it has a valid format.

```
export GCLOUD_PROJECT="your-project-id"
```

Comment: This is not related to `project-id` because when you don't have id it's a different error. I update my question please check it. Because I try to set id and still it is not working. I try to set `env` and set on command via `--project` flag

Answer (score 0):

I think Akshansha Singhal [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68891103/9267296) your question already. Please accept his answer if that resolves it for you. You **NEED** the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable when using python. [See the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#node.js-admin-sdk).

I would like to add a bit though. You are comparing 2 different programming languages. This is really the proverbial apples and oranges.

Actually going through your code a bit, there's an easy explanation. This being `fireo-nodejs/Firestore.js`. [Here](https://github.com/octabytes/fireo-nodejs/blob/main/Firestore.js#L18) you have the project-id in the settings. Going through the python code, there's no setting of the default project-id.

You can either set the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` env variable outside the python code, or you can add some code to check if it's set inside your python.

Likely you would want to add this in the `__init__.py` before the `from google.cloud import firestore` [here](https://github.com/octabytes/FireO/blob/master/src/fireo/__init__.py#L1).

```py
from os import environ

if "GCLOUD_PROJECT" not in environ:
    environ['GCLOUD_PROJECT'] = 'fake-project-id'
```

Comment: This is still not working, I try to set project id but no success

Answer (score 0):

The previous github actions runs described in the issue were failing because the default credentials could not be found. I've found that the most reliable way to manage setting up the Google Cloud SDK is through [`setup-gcloud`](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud).

To make the SDK setup properly, you'll have to add `GCP_PROJECT_ID` and `GCP_SA_KEY` as github secrets. More info can be found on the `setup-gcloud` README.

Note that `GCP_PROJECT_ID` has to be a valid project id
Also I recommend using Base64 encoding for the JSON content in `GCP_SA_KEY`. Github scrubs the logs of the secrets info but just to make sure. [Thread on this](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud/issues/134).

Another interesting issue that I was running into is described [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-secret-manager/issues/82). Basically `setup-gcloud` must be intialized after the python setup or else the python venv won't contain the credentials set by `setup-gcloud`

*Credit goes to [isaacna](https://github.com/isaacna)*